# How to extract 1 screenshot for a video with ffmpeg at a given time?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

There are many tutorials and stuff showing how to extract multiple screenshots from a video using ffmpeg. You set -r and you can even start a certain amount in.

But I just want 1 screenshot at, say 01:23:45 in. Or 1 screenshot at 86% in.

This is all possible with [ffmpegthumbnailer](https://code.google.com/p/ffmpegthumbnailer/) but it's another dependency I don't want to depend on. I want to be able to do it with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 350, accepted):

Use the `-ss` option:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:23:45 -i input -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 output.jpg
```

- For JPEG output use `-q:v` to control output quality. Full range is a linear scale of 1-31 where a lower value results in a higher quality. 2-5 is a good range to try.
- The [select filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) provides an alternative method for more complex needs such as selecting only certain frame types, or 1 per 100, etc.
- Placing `-ss` before the input will be faster. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Seeking](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) and this excerpt from the [`ffmpeg` cli tool documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options):

> `-ss` position (input/output)
>
> When used as an input option (before `-i`), seeks in this input file to position. Note the in most formats it is not possible to seek
> exactly, so `ffmpeg` will seek to the closest seek point before
> position. When transcoding and `-accurate_seek` is enabled (the
> default), this extra segment between the seek point and position will
> be decoded and discarded. When doing stream copy or when
> `-noaccurate_seek` is used, it will be preserved.
>
> When used as an output option (before an output filename), decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach position.
>
> position may be either in seconds or in `hh:mm:ss[.xxx]` form.

Comment: This is MUCH faster. Thank you so much. Putting the -ss first makes a huge difference.

Comment: is there any way to get the n-th frame after the specified time?

Comment: @GuntherPiez I don't see any mention anywhere about possible artifacts.

Comment: Note that `vframes` is obsolete in (at least) version 4.2.2. Per manual "[`vframes`] is an obsolete alias for '`-frames:v`', which you should use instead."

Comment: Works perfect and fast.

Comment: My video is 15 seconds 15.000 Millis
But when I try to get the 15.000 it gives me error but if I try to get 14.800 its ok. 
What can be the problem with latest frame?

Comment: Thank you very much, works as expected with ffmpeg version 4.2.2

Comment: Note that if there is warning `The specified filename 'output.jpg' does not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.\nUse a pattern such as %03d for an image sequence or use the -update opt on (with -frames:v 1 if needed) to write a single image.`, you can put `-update 1` between `-frames:v 1` and `output.jpg`

Answer (score 68):

FFmpeg can do this by seeking to the given timestamp and extracting exactly one frame as an image, see for instance:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -ss 01:23:45 -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

Let's explain the options:

```
-i input file           the path to the input file
-ss 01:23:45            seek the position to the specified timestamp
-frames:v 1             only handle one video frame
output.jpg              output filename, should have a well-known extension
```

The `-ss` parameter accepts a value in the form `HH:MM:SS[.xxx]` or as a number in seconds. If you need a percentage, you need to compute the video duration beforehand.

Comment: Seems to work as expected. I'm currently benchmarking if this is the same speed as using ffmpegthumbnailer.

Comment: Yeah, this approach is super slow. See http://www.peterbe.com/plog/fastest-way-to-take-screencaps-out-of-videos

Comment: try using the -ss option before -i since it will skip the decoding part of the pipeline. This might speedup the process.

Comment: Is there any way to output as PNG to the stream instead of a file?

Comment: @NickeManarin Yes..  `ffmpeg -ss 01:23:45 -i video.mp4 -c:v png -frames:v 1 image.jpg`. Notice that I also put the `-ss` "seek" option ***before*** the input file on the command line, as others have recommended.

Comment: @GlennSlayden Hmm, your example will output 1 frame to 1 file, not multiple frames to the output stream.

Comment: @NickeManarin Oops, sorry, I misread that you just wanted a PNG instead of JPG version of what's shown in this answer. To output entire file as PNG to `stdout`, use this: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:v png -f image2pipe -`  (notice the bare hyphen at the end). I believe `-f rawvideo -` might work instead of `image2pipe` also.