# FFMPEG Pause on specific time for seconds

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am using **ffmpeg** to edit my video, I don't know how to pause a video for seconds.

I need to pause for seconds (like 5 seconds) on specific time of video 
(from 00:10 second to 00:15 second) frame freezes and then continues.

So if my Video is totally 30 seconds, the output will be 35 seconds.

How can i do it with ffmpeg?

Comment: I think you'd need to split the file into 2, take a screenshot at the split, extend the screenshot to X frames, then stitch all three together. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568254/how-to-extract-1-screenshot-for-a-video-with-ffmpeg-at-a-given-time, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/how-to-concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks)

Comment: @user3783243 yes thanks, that's a solution too. If i didn't found a shorter code i will do that .

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1071369